# Fixed row inside a horizontally and vertically scrollable table

Tags: html, css

I'd like every other row in this table to stick to the left but also scroll up and down with the table.  This solution forces every other row to stick in place fixed, so it works left to right, but not up and down.

I've tried a few other css methods like sticky, but to no avail.

I don't like the jquery solutions as they seem to be jittery and so I'd like a pure css solution if it is possible.

```js
for (var i = 0; i <100; i++){
    
    var k = 0

    for (var j = 0; j <100; j++){

        if (k == 0){
                var tr = table.insertRow(-1);  

                tr.style.left = 0
                tr.style.right = 0

                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);

                tabCell.colSpan = "100"
                tabCell.style = "height:44px;"

                div = document.createElement("div")
                div.setAttribute("class","stickyDiv")
                div.innerHTML = "entity " + i
                tabCell.appendChild(div)

                k++
            }
         
        if(k != 0){
            
            if(k == 1){
                var tr = table.insertRow(-1); 
            }

            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = "Column" + j

            k++
        }
    }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
.stickyDiv{
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color:aliceblue
}
```

```html
<body>
    <table id = "table" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: if you do that, it's gonna be like there is no sticky, but as you want just try to change ``position: fixed;`` to ``position: absolute;``, do you want every other row be on the table or to the left side of your page ?

Comment: position: absolute; will allow every other row  to scroll up and down, but will not force every other row to stick to the left when scrolling back and forth.